# #1005 - Can't create table 'test_db.demandes_gardes' (errno: 150) (Details…)

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I can't execute this query on phpmyadmin for upgrading my sql test_db:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `demandes_gardes` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nom` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `prenom` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `matricule` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `chambre` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `autre` TEXT NULL,
  `garde_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `statut_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `created` DATETIME NULL,
  `updated` DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_demandes_gardes_gardes1_idx` (`garde_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_demandes_gardes_statuts1_idx` (`statut_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_demandes_gardes_gardes1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`garde_id`)
    REFERENCES `gardes` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_demandes_gardes_statuts1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`statut_id`)
    REFERENCES `statuts` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I get :

> #1005 - Can't create table 'test_db.demandes_gardes' (errno: 150)

Any help please ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ensure the `statuts` and `gardes` tables have the id column set as a primary key.  I tested the same code and only received the 1005 error when one of the foreign keys was not a primary key in its own table.  This is assuming there is a valid statuts and gardes table each with an integer `id` column.

```
ALTER TABLE `statuts` 
CHANGE COLUMN `id` `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `gardes` 
CHANGE COLUMN `id` `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```